# How can I use Clearpath Husky Simulations on ROS2 Humble?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble, husky, clearpath

I'm relatively new to the ROS community and recently wanted to try out ROS2. I was using Clearpath's Husky to test and learn about ROS, Gazebo, RViz etc. on ROS using Husky's model, simulations, launch files, URDF YAML files and so on.

I want to use Husky in ROS2 too. While I was checking ROS2 Humble packages I saw 2-3 days ago  they released new husky packages, metapackages and some demos for Husky. I just cant find a way to use it the same way that I used in ROS Noetic. It would be really appreciated if you can help me use Husky or at least an alternative that I can use to learn and understand the ROS2.

Thanks.

Comment: Another easy to understand alternative you can use to get started is the [bcr_bot](https://github.com/blackcoffeerobotics/bcr_bot). It allows the usage of both Gazebo Classic and Fortress with a range of configurable sensors! We are actively maintaining it.

Answer (score 1):

There are tutorials on how to install and use the Clearpath ROS 2 simulator on the docs website at https://docs.clearpathrobotics.com/docs/ros/tutorials/simulator/install and https://docs.clearpathrobotics.com/docs/ros/tutorials/simulator/simulate

There are also navigation tutorials and a lot of documentation available on that website as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I successfully installed all the required packages, dependencies etc. But I cant get gazebo or rviz to detect robot.yaml file. I configured the location and content of the file, followed the instructions but it still doesn't bring up the robot (husky in my case) itself on simulations.

Comment: I would need more details to be able to help you troubleshoot this. Usually people either have issues because they 1) missed a step in the install instructions 2) put the robot.yaml in the wrong spot or 3) have a malformed robot.yaml file. Can you share the terminal output, the command that you ran and where you put your robot.yaml file?